# How to use PFQuery getObjectWithId?

Tags: swift, pfquery, parse-server, pfobject, heroku-api

Working with `PFObject` and `PFQuery` I am having trouble debugging this piece of code:

```
.......

if let someContents = object.valueForKey("contents") {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "TheContentList")
    do {let object = try query.getObjectWithId(someContents.objectId)
        print(object)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

With the code above I get this compiler message for the line with `getObjectWithId`:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String?!' to type 'String' in coercion
```

If I change:

```
query.getObjectWithId(someContents.objectId)
```

to:

```
query.getObjectWithId("xyz23AcSXh")
```

It compiles and inside the debugger I get this:

```
(lldb) p someContents.objectId
(String?!) $R4 = "xyz23AcSXh"
```

And the program prints an object as expected.

So the question is: **how should I write the line query.getObjectWithId to be able to use what is inside someContents?**

Comment: Did  you try with `query.getObjectWithId(someContents.objectId!)` .. check the exclamation mark.

Comment: What you write does not work. I get the error message from the compiler:
`Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`
But following on this: `query.getObjectWithId(someContents.objectId!!)`
works. So you put me on the right track. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `objectId`, is an `Explicitly Unwrapped Optional`, of an `Optional`. If you're sure it contains a `String`, unwrap it using:

```
let object = try query.getObjectWithId(someContents.objectId!!)
```

Otherwise, if you're not sure:

```
if let objectId = someContents.objectId, id = objectId {
    let object = try query.getObjectWithId(id)
}
```